# Different types of AC in RP

Tags: homebrew

I'm looking for references to other rp systems that have different ways of determining when you would take damage. My current RP group as started to fizzle out, saying that the newer systems have changed to much from what they like are now looking for a new system to try out. our main concern is how dynamic combat can be. Mostly looking for the statistics behind how their respective defenses work.

Example: A target tries to land an attack on me, what mechanics are in play for me to: Dodge/Tank it/Redirect it? Something along these lines would be appreciated.

Since I'm only played D&D 2e-3.5e and Pathfinder, I consider my knowledge on this subject limited. Any help is appreciated, and anything goes here, be as complex as you need to be.

Comment: I'm a little confused about what the question is here. Are you looking for suggestions on a new tabletop game that uses AC? Also, by "newer systems" do you mean D&D 5e?

Comment: If you're looking for the various ways games handle physical damage (and the avoidance of it), this is far too broad. [There are several thousand RPG systems](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/1475/1204), and no two games I've played have handled the concept of physical damage quite the same way (except those that derive themselves from D&D). You may be better off just reading some other RPGs! We can also [talk about this in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) once you have 20 rep.

Comment: You may also find it useful to take the [tour] and browse the [Help].